# What is/are the specific genre/s of electronic music producer 'k?d'?

Tags: identify-this-genre, electronic-music

I started listening to [k?d](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%3Fd)'s tracks some months ago, and I fell in love with his style. I wanted to know what his genre could be called? I know that he produces different genres, but mainly he does stuff like:

[The Chainsmokers - Young (k?d Remix)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HnVGQbF4nS0)
[k?d - Lose Myself (feat. Phil Good)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1AEJY-2Ku0Q)
[k?d - Discover](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FdRJcsKFzJ0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think k?d produces glitch hop / 110 bpm.

Just look at this video by Dylan Tallchief:

[HOW TO K?D](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C6gn1H_D7e0)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your contribution. Can you explain a little more? In case the link dies, it would be nice to have some quotes to expand your answer.